# Ember.js Dynamic router not loading template using serialize

Tags: ember.js

I have a route as #/0, #/1, #/2 this loads the corresponding template when a user name is clicked.
But the following error is thrown when i click the username,

> Error while loading route: TypeError: Object # has no method 'addArrayObserver'

But when i directly visit the url localhost:8080/dynam.html#/0 , i get the output as,

> 25

Templates:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2>Names</h2>
  <ul>
  {{#each model}}
      <li>{{#linkTo "test" this}}{{this.firstName}} {{this.lastName}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
  {{/each}}
   </ul>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
  <h2>Item Loaded</h2>
  {{#each model}}
      <li>{{#linkTo "test" this}} {{Age}} {{/linkTo}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </script>
```

App.js:

> ```
>     App = Ember.Application.create({});
>
> App.Router.map(function() {
>     this.route('test', {path: '/:id'});
> });
>
> App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
>   model: function(id){
>       return [
>               {id: 0, firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden'},
>               {id: 1, firstName: 'Luke', lastName: 'Melia'},
>               {id: 2, firstName: 'Formerly Alex', lastName: 'Matchneer'}
>           ];
>   },
>   serialize: function(model) {
>     return {id: model.id};
>   }                         
> });
>
> App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
>   model: function(){
>     return App.TestObj.getArray();
>   }
> });
>
> App.TestObj = Ember.Object.extend();
> App.TestObj.reopenClass({
>   testArr : [ {Age: '26' } ],
>   test1Arr : [],
>   getArray : function(){
>   this.testArr.forEach(function(obj){
>           this.test1Arr.pushObject(App.TestObj.create(obj));
>         }, this);
>   return this.test1Arr;
>   }
>
> })
> ```

Answer (score 0):

When entering a serialized route via

```
{{#link-to routname model}}
```

the Model hook will not be run.  Instead, the model is being set by whatever input value you have set in the {{#link-to}} helper.

So in the code you have written, when you click

```
{{#linkTo "test" this}}
```

You are entering the "test" route and setting the model to whatever person you clicked.  For example, if you selected the first person, you would set the model of TestRoute to:

```
{id: 0, firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden'}
```

Now you render your test template, which includes a {{#each model}} helper... but your model only has a single object in it, so it fails to run correctly.

On the other hand, when you enter a route directly using a url, the model hook *will* run.  That's why you're getting a value for age when running it in this way.

In general, for serialized paths, you should use the model hook to retrieve information that normally would be  passed in by default.  For example:

```
model: function(param){
    var id = param.id; //This will return the serialized portion of your url
    return someFunction(id); //Use that serialized value to look up the correct model
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where should I use the model which returns "someFunction(id)", in IndexRoute or TestRoute also what should be the structure of my model.

Comment: Your model structure should be whatever is necessary.  There is no gold standard, it's just a dumping ground for the relevant information that you need.